# How can I vertically align a list item marker

Tags: css, html-lists, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to increase the size of my list item markers with the following CSS:

```css
li::marker {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Gromit</li>
</ul>
```

The resize works perfectly, but the markers are no longer aligned vertically with the list item contents.

I tried using `vertical-align`, but I can't seem to get the desired result:

```css
li {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
li::marker {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Gromit</li>
</ul>
```

I tried using `position: absolute` on the marker to move it. I also tried `transform: translateY(x);`, but I can't get either to move the marker at all for some reason… Plus I would hate to have to go back and fiddle with `x` every time I change the font size of the list item or marker.

Here is one of my attempts as an example:

```css
li::marker {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  transform: translateY(1000rem);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Gromit</li>
</ul>
```

I've seen a lot of similar questions, but none of them seem to provide a solution which:

- Doesn't introduce extra HTML markup
- Doesn't introduce custom values that would need to change if the font size of the list item (or that of the marker) changes.
- Doesn't require JavaScript

That being said, if I missed something, feel free to point me in the right direction and I will mark this as a duplicate myself.

Answer (score 10):

Frankly, I wouldn't use [**`marker`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker) as your styling options are deliberately restricted. Use `before` instead

> Only certain CSS properties can be used in a rule with ::marker as a selector:
>
> All font properties
>
> The white-space property, color, text-combine-upright, unicode-bidi and direction properties & The content property

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

li::before {
  content: "";
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: grey;
  margin-right: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Gromit</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I searched way too long for this. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

The before pseudo element solution can give you what you want (and personally it's what I'd use) but in case it is of use to others who for some reason are constrained to using marker, it is possible to set the content to a Unicode large circle as in this snippet and color it.

```css
li::marker {
  content: '\2B24 ';
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Gromit</li>
</ul>
```

Note: tested OK on Chrome/Edge and Firefox on Windows 10. However, Safari on an iPad IOS (14) is showing a smaller circle.

Comment: If I add `color: red;`, that works for me on latest chrome on mac. Are you saying that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Thanks for spotting - I thought I'd tried color but obviously not correctly. I've edited the answer. However, in doing that I noticed that a large circle was shown fine on my Windows 10 but on Safari (on iPad IOS 14) it took the color OK but showed a small circle. I'll investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Add ::before with css:

```
content: "";
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```